# Контроллеры в Spring MVC(Java)

Tags: spring, java-ee, spring-mvc

Здравствуйте, недавно начал изучать Spring MVC и наткнулся на проблему того, что не получается вернуть разные данные с контроллера и разного рода JSON объекты, к примеру вот код:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logIn", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String auethentificate(@RequestParam(value = "login") String login, @RequestParam(value = "password") String password){
    RoleUser roleUser = auethentification.authenticate(login, password);
    switch (roleUser) {
        case ADMIN:
            // Здесь нужно перенаправить к другому контроллеру, чтобы он вернул страницу
            return "redirect:/adminRoom/showPage";
        case USER:
            // Здесь нужно перенаправить к другому контроллеру, чтобы он вернул страницу
            olympiad.startOlympiad(login, password);
            return "redirect:/tasks/showPage";
        case UNKNOWN:
            // Здесь нужно вернуть просто текст и с помощью AJAX его отобразить на клиенте
            return "Не правильные данные";
    }
    // Здесь нужно вернуть просто текст и с помощью AJAX его отобразить на клиенте
    return "Ошибка";
}
```

Суть этого кода заключается в следующем, если пользователь ввел корректные данные то его нужно перенаправить на страницу, а если не то отправить ошибку и на JS с помощью AJAX вывести ее, но к сожалению получается либо только вернуть страницу, либо только текст и никак по другому...
И вот еще пример кода:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showPageTasks(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("questions", olympiad.getQuestions());
    modelAndView.addObject("logs", olympiad.getLogsOfRunningTest());
    modelAndView.addObject("statisticUser", olympiad.getStatisticUser());
    modelAndView.setViewName("tasks");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Здесь возвращаются разного рода объекты вместе со страницей(т.е. при помощи ее перезагрузки), а можно ли сделать как-нибудь чтобы эти объекты возвращались через JSON также все вместе без страницы, по отдельности все прекрасно работает, но мне нужно вернуть все вместе за раз.
Жду корректного ответа, либо приведение возможного кода или может быть статью в интернете, описывающую как это сделать, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если у вас авторизация происходит через ajax, то лучше по моему использовать RestController, а результат (в том числе и редирект) обрабатывать на клиенте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно инжектнуть [HttpServletResponse](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) в дополнительный параметр и отсылать редирект через него.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String auethentificate(@RequestParam(value = "login") String login,
                              @RequestParam(value = "password") String password,
                              HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    RoleUser roleUser = auethentification.authenticate(login, password);
    switch (roleUser) {
        case ADMIN:
            response.sendRedirect("/adminRoom/showPage");
        case USER:
            olympiad.startOlympiad(login, password);
            response.sendRedirect("/tasks/showPage");
        case UNKNOWN:
            return "Не правильные данные";
    }
    return "Ошибка";
}
```

Второй вопрос тоже просто решается

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, List<String>> showPageTasks(){
    Map<String, List<String>> response = new HashMap<>();
    response.put("questions", olympiad.getQuestions());
    response.put("logs", olympiad.getLogsOfRunningTest());
    response.put("statisticUser", olympiad.getStatisticUser());
    return response;
}
```

надо только структуру возвращаемых данных под себя подогнать. Если questions,  logs и statisticUser - имеют разные типы, можно объявить класс с соответствующими полями и возвращать его вместо мапы.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите, чтобы в исключительных ситуация возвращался JSON, следует использовать **@ExceptionHandler**:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logIn", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String auethentificate(@RequestParam(value = "login") String login, @RequestParam(value = "password") String password){
    RoleUser roleUser = auethentification.authenticate(login, password);
    switch (roleUser) {
        case ADMIN:
            // Здесь нужно перенаправить к другому контроллеру, чтобы он вернул страницу
            return "redirect:/adminRoom/showPage";
        case USER:
            // Здесь нужно перенаправить к другому контроллеру, чтобы он вернул страницу
            olympiad.startOlympiad(login, password);
            return "redirect:/tasks/showPage";
        case UNKNOWN:
            // Здесь нужно вернуть просто текст и с помощью AJAX его отобразить на клиенте
            throw new MyNotValidDataException();
    }
    // Здесь нужно вернуть просто текст и с помощью AJAX его отобразить на клиенте
    throw new MyNotValidDataException();
    }
```

И теперь обработка исключений, выброшенных из котроллера:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MyNotValidDataException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handle(){
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Неправильные данные");
    }
}
```

Подробнее https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно разобраться в разнице между традиционным SpringMVC контроллером (используется вместе с View и маркируется @Controller) и @RestController-ом который тоже является частью Spring MVC, но в отличие от классического контроллера объекты которые им возвращаются записываются сразу в Response как JSON/XML.

Ответ от @Andrey Dorohovich верен (за исключением мелочей, из-за которых код не скомпилируется). Я бы тоже порекомендовал использование ExceptionHandler-а для обработки не стандартных ситуаций, как в первой части вашего вопроса. В ExceptionHandler-е вы также сможете оперировать HTTP Response Code-ами, чтобы например послать HTTP 403 (Access Denied) или HTTP 401 (Unauthorized), в случае если введен неверный пароль или пользователь не имеет необходимых прав.

Ответ от @Hivemaster тоже верен. Добавление @ResponseBody к методу в классическом контроллере фактически переключает его в RestController режим. То есть возвращаемый этим методом объект будет записан в Response.

Comment: Спасибо, я исправил.